# Python JSON dict to dataframe no rows

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

So after hours of unsuccesfull googling I finally decided to post this here.

I am trying to convert some data obtained by an API call to a 
 `Pandas.DataFrame()`

This is my code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data_as_list = response.json()['data']
for dct in data_as_list:
    json_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dct)
```

Unfortunately, the returned dataframe only contains the column names, but no row data at all, even though the dictionary has some. I already tried `from_dict` and `pd.read_json()` (after dumping it into a JSON string). But all of these had the same
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwppa.png).

The data is a nested dictionary in JSON format and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ojy.png)

Comment: please post a sample of the `dict`, i.e. the json response

Comment: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize;
json_normalize(data['data']); hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make DataFrames From python lists (that contains dictionaries or lists (nested list)) like this code:

```
 json_df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
pd.DataFrame(data_as_list)
```